# What has been changed to the MPXJ library used to access MS Project 2010?

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I have an old project that uses MPXJ library to access MS Project 2010. However it doesn't get the files save as Project 2010 format even if I uses the latest MPXJ 4.0. What else do I need to do to get the files of that format? I've searched MPXJ website but there seems to be no document about the changes and a tutorial to modify existing codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not need to make any changes to read Project 2010 files. The MPXJ API has not changed significantly with the 4.0 release: there are a few new Task and Resource attributes. If you are using the "presentation" information from the MPP file, you'll find that colors have changed from being represented by an enumeration to being Java Color types. That's pretty much it.

If you are still having specific problems reading Project 2010 files, feel free to raise a bug at SourceForge, or drop me a note directly.

Cheers!

Jon

Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ